# Why are "said" and "paid"/"laid" pronounced differently?

Tags: pronunciation, phonology, vowels, old-english, middle-english

The words *say, pay, lay* are phonemically **/seɪ/**, **/peɪ/** and **/leɪ/** respectively (with the diphthong /eɪ/). Their past and past participles are respectively: **/sɛd/** (or /sed/), /peɪd/ and /leɪd/. The past/past participle (and present simple singular) of "said" contains a vowel instead of the expected diphthong /eɪ/.

[*Say*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/say) and [*lay*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lay) are both Old English words while [*pay*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pay) is from Old French through Middle English. "Say" and "lay" belonged to the same verb class in Old English, if I understand it correctly. That's why their past/past participle are spelled the same.

I didn't have much luck tracing their roots and finding what happened that caused "said" to have the vowel /ɛ/ instead of the diphthong /eɪ/.

So why does "said" have a vowel and not a diphthong?

Comment: Probably because its pronunciation was influenced by its Old English original term : *Past tense said developed from Old English segde.* https://www.etymonline.com/word/say?ref=etymonline_crossreference#etymonline_v_22810

Comment: Probably because it's usually used in weakly stressed positions.

Comment: Unquestionably because English orthography is psychotic.

Comment: English spelling was codified, largely by printers, somewhere between 1600 and 1750. Around 1600, when Shakespeare wrote, in his poetry he rhymed *said* with *allay'd* (Sonnet 66), with *stay'd* (*Venus and Adonis*), and with *afraid* (*A Lover's Complaint*).